# Unable to add products in Magento 2.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I just installed `Magento 2.0.2` on my local machine. But, I am not able to add new products. The `add product page` keep reloading.

[image]

There is nothing in logs. All logs are empty beside `system.log`, which has only the following information.

```
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Theme::system_design_theme was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design_schedule was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_store was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::dashboard was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_tools was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_convert was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_cache was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_communications was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_seo was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content_elements was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_settings was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_attributes was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::other_settings was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_other_settings was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::setup_wizard was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backup::system_tools_backup was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_manage was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_online was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_group was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_AdminNotification::system_adminnotification was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Indexer::system_index was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_page was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_block was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_products was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_categories was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_attributes was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_sets was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::inventory was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::search_terms was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Widget::cms_widget_instance was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CheckoutAgreements::sales_checkoutagreement was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Config::system_config was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_rates was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_symbols was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Downloadable::report_products_downloads was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_import was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_export was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_history was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Email::template was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_users was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_roles was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_locks was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_operation was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_order was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_invoice was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_shipment was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_transactions was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::system_order_statuses was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_extensions was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_integrations was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Marketplace::partners was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo_catalog was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_template was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_queue was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_subscriber was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_problem was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_SalesRule::promo_quote was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::report_salesroot_paypal_settlement_reports was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::paypal_billing_agreement was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_marketing was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_sales was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_tax was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_invoiced was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_shipping was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_refunded was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_coupons was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_product was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_abandoned was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_bestsellers was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_sold was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_viewed was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_lowstock was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_accounts was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_totals was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_orders was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics_refresh was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::report_search_term was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_ratings was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_customer was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_product was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sitemap::catalog_sitemap was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rules was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rates was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_TaxImportExport::system_convert_tax was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_UrlRewrite::urlrewrite was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_EncryptionKey::system_crypt_key was processed [] []
[2016-03-09 12:36:53] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Variable::system_variable was processed [] []
```

I checked permissions too and all are fine. No `JS/jQuery` error in console.

Comment: Found any solution this?

Comment: work on different browser but not on firefox